# Return list of records based on soql query results

Tags: apex, soql

I have two objects that has a many to many relationship with each other. Ideally, I would create a junction object for this but it would be data heavy hence we're trying to avoid it. I was thinking that it may be possible using apex since they have sort of criteria. Below is what I'm trying to achieve:

**ObjectA__c has the ff records:**
A-1 record:

- Name: A-1
- ExtId__c: 000001
- Soql_Criteria__c: Family__c LIKE '%ABC%'

A-2 record:

- Name: A-2
- ExtId__c: 000002
- Soql_Criteria__c: Family__c LIKE '%DEF%'

A-3 record:

- Name: A-3
- ExtId__c: 000003
- Soql_Criteria__c: Family__c LIKE '%GHI%'

**ObjectB__c has the ff records:**
B-1 record:

- Name: B-1
- Family__c: ABC-123

B-2 record:

- Name: B-2
- Family__c: ABC-456

B-3 record:

- Name: B-3
- Family__c: DEF-123

Then I have this apex class that queries all ObjectA__c then combines the "SOQL_Criteria__c" field value into one string:

```
for(ObjectA__c objA: [SELECT Id, Name, ExtId__c, SOQL_Criteria__c
                      FROM ObjectA__c]){
     mapSOQLCriteriaAndId.put(SOQL_Criteria__c,Id);
}

if(!mapSOQLCriteriaAndId.isEmpty())
{
    for(String soqlCriteria : mapSOQLCriteriaAndId.keySet()){
        if(soqlCriteriaCombined == '')
            soqlCriteriaCombined = '('+soqlCriteria+')';
        else {
            soqlCriteriaCombined = soqlCriteriaCombined + 'OR (' + soqlCriteria + ')';
        }
    }

    String soqlQueryToExecute = 'SELECT Name, Family__c FROM ObjectB__c WHERE '+ soqlCriteriaCombined;

    listObjectB = database.query(soqlQueryToExecute);
}
```

Note: I need the SOQL_Criteria__c to be the keyset because I have ObjectA__c records with same SOQL_Criteria__c so above is just a sample

listObjectB would contain records from ObjectB__c that meets the criteria, my next step would be to return ObjectA__c records based on the returned ObjectB__c records. So from above sample records, my apex class should only return 'A-1' and 'A-2' records.

Is there a way to do this via Apex without executing multiple queries? I'm open to other ideas as well. Highly appreciate any help!